# Is there a way in Powershell to append or prepend the value of a variable to the output of a piplined command

Tags: powershell

I have the one-liner:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | select name | where {$_.name -like 'HI_*'}
```

and I would like to add the value of `$username` to every row of the output, and get the output in CSV format using `ConvertTo-CSV` (or similar).

e.g., output would look like this:

HI_Users,JBloggs
HI_Supervisors,JBloggs
HI_Admins,JBloggs

This is needed for downstream processing on another system.

Comment: So why don't you extend your command with ```| foreach-object { … } | export-csv ...``` I'd also change the sequence of select and where...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [calculated property](https://foxdeploy.com/2014/05/18/working-out-select-object-with-calculated-properties/) where you would include your variable.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | 
    where-object{$_.name -like 'HI_*'} | 
    select @{label="username";Expression={$username}},name
```

No need to do anything fancy with that either for CSV output. Just pipe to `Export-CSV`